# Debugging specialize and/or apply errors in Coq

Tags: binary-search-tree, coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to figure out the source of the following error with the  `apply (list2map_not_in_default [(k, v)] i) in H2.` command.

Here is the `list2map_not_in_default` type:

```
list2map_not_in_default
     : forall (al : list (key * V)) (i : key),
       ~ (exists v : V, In (i, v) al) -> list2map al i = default
```

And the error:

```
Error:
Unable to apply lemma of type
 "~ (exists v0 : V, In (i, v0) [(k, v)]) -> list2map [(k, v)] i = default"
on hypothesis of type "~ (exists v : V, In (i, v) [(k, v)])".
```

Alternatively `apply (list2map_not_in_default [(k, v)] i) in H2.` , can be seen as the following error, whereby you can see my context fully.

```
Error:
In environment
V : Type
default : V
lo : key
l : tree
k : key
v : V
r : tree
hi : key
H0_ : SearchTree' lo l k
H0_0 : SearchTree' (S k) r hi
i : nat
Hleft : ~ (exists v : V, In (i, v) (slow_elements l))
H : i < k
H0 : k <> i
H1 : list2map (slow_elements l) i = default
H2 : ~ (exists v : V, In (i, v) [(k, v)])
The term "H2" has type "~ (exists v : V, In (i, v) [(k, v)])"
while it is expected to have type "~ (exists v0 : V, In (?i, v0) ?al)".
```

Earlier in the proof I use the exact same lemma `specialize (list2map_not_in_default _ _ Hleft).` with no problems.

This applied in the following context

```
  V : Type
  default : V
  lo : key
  l : tree
  k : key
  v : V
  r : tree
  hi : key
  H0_ : SearchTree' lo l k
  H0_0 : SearchTree' (S k) r hi
  i : nat
  Hleft : ~ (exists v : V, In (i, v) (slow_elements l))
  H : i < k
  H0 : k <> i
  ============================
  list2map (slow_elements l ++ [(k, v)] ++ slow_elements r) i =
  list2map (slow_elements l) i
```

yields a goal with the desired application.

```
  list2map (slow_elements l) i = default ->
  list2map (slow_elements l ++ [(k, v)] ++ slow_elements r) i =
  list2map (slow_elements l) i
```

What is happening here?  Any suggestions on how I can fix it?

Comment: Long shot, but try replacing `apply` with `eapply`.

Answer (score 1):

The unification algorithm used by `apply in` is exceedingly weak. There is nothing you can do about it (except opening bug reports and hoping someone fixes it). Just use some other tactic. As you already noticed, `specialize` works better, since you are explicitly writing a lambda-term. Another similar tactic is `assert (H3 := list2map_not_in_default _ _ Hleft)`. Or you can go to the most expressive tactic of all: `(simple) refine (let H3 := list2map_not_in_default _ _ Hleft in _)`.

Comment: There's also `pose proof`.